# Argument is not passed from front to back-end

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I have to said, am totally newbee in AngularJS. I want to add register option in my application. I got some example and I want to add register option.
I've done something like this:

```
var services = angular.module('exampleApp.services', ['ngResource']);


services.factory('UserService', function ($resource) {

return $resource('rest/user/:action', {},
        {
            authenticate: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {'action': 'authenticate'},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }
        }
);
});


function LoginController($scope, $rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, UserService) {

$scope.rememberMe = false;

$scope.login = function () {

    UserService.authenticate($.param({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}), function (authenticationResult) {
        var authToken = authenticationResult.token;
        $rootScope.authToken = authToken;
        if ($scope.rememberMe) {
            $cookieStore.put('authToken', authToken);
        }
        UserService.get(function (user) {
            $rootScope.user = user;
            $location.path("/");
        });
    });
};

$scope.register = function () {
    $scope.user = new UserService();
    console.log($scope.user);
    $scope.user.$save(function () {
        $location.path('/');
    });

};
```

}
;

```
angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'exampleApp.services'])
    .config(
            ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

                    $routeProvider.when('/create', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/create.html',
                        controller: CreateController
                    });

                    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                        controller: LoginController
                    });
        //more stuff here

});

@Component
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource {

    //some field here

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User register(User user) {
          return this.userDao.save(user);
    }
```

The thing is, that I am reaching handling in java `register` method, but my User parameter is null.

I also tried to use:

```
    @POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User register( @QueryParam("password") String password, @QueryParam("username") String username) {

    return this.userDao.save(new User(username, password));
}
```

and

```
 $scope.register = function () {
    $scope.user = new UserService();
    console.log($scope.user);

    $http({
        url: 'user',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.persons = data;
    });

};
```

But I have received

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

In browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with passing JSON from Angular.JS correctly.

You should not try to serialize JSON object yourself with `$.params`,  pass the object as is and let Angular handle it, instead:

```
UserService.authenticate({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}, function (authenticationResult) {
```

You should correctly indicate that you are going to send JSON, not `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`:

```
return $resource('rest/user/:action', {},
    {
        authenticate: {
            method: 'POST',
            responseType: 'json',
            params: {'action': 'authenticate'},
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            }
        }
    }
```

The rest of the initial code looks fine, no need for `@QueryParam` on Java side, you are going to send and return JSON, `@QueryParam` is for the case when you are sending params inside URL itself.

One thing though. You are having `authenticate` action on Angular.JS side, but on Java side, you have `register` action. The action name should obviously match.

Comment: Authenticate working fine, I have troubles with register function